# How to save images with the same name to the different direction using PIL and os.path?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, os.path

While trying to split the path to get a name, I get the traceback: 
`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not JpegImageFile` . How can I solve it or is there other methods?

I try to save resized images with the same name to a different direction. For this reason, I use os.path.split() functions.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
import os
images = glob.glob("/Users/marialavrovskaa/Desktop/6_1/*")
path = "/Users/marialavrovskaa/Desktop/2.2/"
quality_val=95
for image in images:
    image = Image.open(image)
    image.thumbnail((640, 428), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image_path_and_name = os.path.split(image)
    image_name_and_ext = os.path.splitext(image[0])
    name = image_name_and_ext[0] + '.png'
    name = os.path.splitext(image)[0] + '.png'
    file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
    image.save(file_path, quality=quality_val)
```

Comment: `image = Image.open(image)` Because you're overwriting the `image` variable from a path to the image object itself, you can't use `image` to mean the path later. Use a separate variable for the object for avoid this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By the code above you will get image in thumbnails I recommend to use resize function because from resize you can maintain you aspect ratio that helps you in getting better results.

```
image.thumbnail((640, 428), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

this line of code is converting your thumbnail.which is not good approach of resizing. Try the code below.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

PATH = "F:\\FYP DATASET\\images\\outliers Dataset\\Not Outliers\\"
Copy_to_path="F:\\FYP DATASET\\images\\outliers Dataset\\"

for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(PATH, filename)) # images are color images
    img = img.resize((224,224), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(Copy_to_path+filename+'.jpeg')
```

In this code you are taking images directly from folder resize them and saving them to other location with same name. All the images are processing one by one So you need not worry to load all the images at once into the memory.

Comment: how is accuracy being reduced by using the thumbnail functIon?

Comment: To be honest, at first I tried the same approach, but it seemed that with resize () the accuracy was much worse.

Comment: only major difference between the two is that `resize()` can enlarge the image from its original dimensions, but `thumbnail()` can not. And, `resize()` returns a copy of image object therefore you have to store it in a separate variable after calling the function, but `thumbnail()` modified the image object in place, and does not require any assignment after the call.

Comment: @MariaLavrovskaya 2 days before I tried resizing data than using thumbnails that increase my accuracy. That might be vary from scenario to scenario

Comment: @MariaLavrovskaya but if you remove resize line with thumbnail line this code will work perfect and this code is easy to understand.

Comment: I have edited the question providing the solution for the problem. Hope it will help if whoever stuck with the same problem in the future :)

Comment: @MariaLavrovskaya If a answer works for you,  you should mark it as correct.  Rather then editing the question,  and writing the solution in it. In that way the answer would be more visible to anyone who came across the same problem in the future.

Comment: Thank you. I marked it. I am new to stackoverflow, so I learn all the rules step by step.

Comment: There is a logical error in your code. `img.save(Copy_to_path+filename+'.jpeg')` will always result in wrong filenames. It is because, `filename` variable will always store the filename and the extension. i.e. possible filename values are `example.png`, `example1.png`, `marksetchell.jpg`, `vasudeos.gif` etc. as you can see the value will always contain the filename + the extension of the file. Therefore, when you try to save the file using `img.save(Copy_to_path+filename+'.jpeg')`, any original file ex `example.png` will be saved as `example.png.jpeg`.

Comment: Which is definitely unwanted, as we wanted the file to be saved with its original filename and extension. So instead change the code to `img.save(Copy_to_path+filename)` this will save the original file as it is to the destination location. In your method any file extension would have been saved as a `.jpeg`.

Comment: Have you tried the code? If I didn't specify the extension this will give an error. You should try the code before finding out errors in someones code and I think Question is for resizing images only so why do I write extra code?. @VasuDeo.S. I restricted the image to save in .jpg because I need only images to be resized.

Comment: It's not about resize. It's the fact that you are trying to save any image file explicitly as a `.jpeg`, which is okay, if you had removed its previous extension from it. But in your case any image file will be saved as `filename.oldextension.jpeg` which is definitely not good, as it creates a lot of ambiguity for the user to identify its extension in the first look.

Comment: @SohaibAnwaar and your code has 3 useless imports in it too `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`,
`import matplotlib.image as mpimg` and 
`import PIL`

Comment: imports are the logical issue ? See I removed.

Comment: No, The logical error were your extension conversion to `.jpeg`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
import os

images = glob.glob("Source_path")
path = r"Destination_path"
quality_val=95

for image in images:
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.thumbnail((640, 428), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    name = os.path.split(image)
    file_path = os.path.join(path, name[1])
    img.save(file_path, quality=quality_val)
```

The primary problem with your code was that you were using a variable and an object under the same name `image`. Which was causing problems.

**LOGICAL ERRORS:-**

- `image_path_and_name` is a needless variable in the code, as it is
  used for nothing.
- `name` has been initialized with totally different values twice,
  instead use `name = os.path.split(image)` which serves the purpose
  of both.
- you should not try to explicitly define the extension of each image
  as `.png` as it might create issues when dealing with other image
  formats.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Why do you use 1 here  `file_path = os.path.join(path, name[1])`?

Comment: `os.path.split()` returns directory location and filename (with extension), therefore `name[1]` will be used to reference the filename with its extension. Ex. If a location is `"C:\Users\vasudeos\OneDrive\Desktop\30-05-2019.tmp"` then upon passing it via `os.path.split()` we will get a tuple like `('C:\\Users\\vasudeos\\OneDrive\\Desktop', '30-05-2019.tmp')` now if we do `os.path.split()[1]` we will get `30-05-2019.tmp` (filename with its extension)

Comment: @MariaLavrovskaya I would recommend you to read the logical error section of my answer, It will help you out greatly in the future, while working on PIL

Answer (score 0):

```
for image in images:
    image = Image.open(image)
    image.thumbnail((640, 428), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image_path_and_name = os.path.split(image)
```

When you say `image = Image.open(image)`, you're overwriting the loop variable also named `image`, and it's no longer a splittable string.

Change one of the `image` variables to a different name.

Answer (score 0):

firstly,
`image_name_and_ext = os.path.splitext(image[0])`

should be 
`image_name_and_ext = os.path.splitext(image_path_and_name[1])`

because image is string so `image[0]` just get first character of image not useless in this case

secondly,

`name = os.path.splitext(image)[0] + '.png'` equal `image`

`name = os.path.splitext(image)[0]` should return path of image not include extention

to solve this problem, you can try:

```
for image in images:
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.thumbnail((640, 428), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    name = os.path.split(image)
    file_path = os.path.join(path, name[1])
    image.save(file_path, quality=quality_val)
```